# How do i make slideshow which is while load start and on hover it stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I just created a div for my slideshow. Below I have script for make this slideshow workable using next and previous arrows. I want to make same slide to work auto slideshow and on hover it stop.
any one can help me out how do I do ? as I am beginner to this

```
<div id="slideshow">
               <a href="#" class="slideshow-prev">&laquo;</a> 
               <ul>
                    <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="photo1" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="photo2" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="photo3" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="photo4" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="photo5" /></li>
               </ul>
                <a href="#" class="slideshow-next">&raquo;</a> 
            </div>
               <script>

                //an image width in pixels 
                var imageWidth = $('#slideshow ul li').width();


                //DOM and all content is loaded 
                $(window).ready(function() {

                    var currentImage = 0;

                    //set image count 
                    var allImages = $('#slideshow li img').length;

                    //setup slideshow frame width
                    $('#slideshow ul').width(allImages*imageWidth);

                    //attach click event to slideshow buttons
                    $('.slideshow-next').click(function(){

                        //increase image counter
                        currentImage++;
                        //if we are at the end let set it to 0
                        if(currentImage>=allImages) currentImage = 0;
                        //calcualte and set position
                        setFramePosition(currentImage);

                    });

                    $('.slideshow-prev').click(function(){

                        //decrease image counter
                        currentImage--;
                        //if we are at the end let set it to 0
                        if(currentImage<0) currentImage = allImages-1;
                        //calcualte and set position
                        setFramePosition(currentImage);

                    });

                });

                //calculate the slideshow frame position and animate it to the new position
                function setFramePosition(pos){

                    //calculate position
                    var px = imageWidth*pos*-1;
                    //set ul left position
                    $('#slideshow ul').animate({
                        left: px
                    }, 300);
                }
            </script>
```

I just created a div for my slideshow. Below I have script for make this slideshow workable using next and previous arrows. I want to make same slide to work auto slideshow and on hover it stop. 
    Any one can help me out how do I do ? as I am beginner to this 
**If possible, can someone please provide me with a JavaScript code that will automatically play the slide show**

Comment: Check this example for how to pause on hover: http://tobia.github.io/Pause/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below mentioned code inside of script tag:

```
var time;
$(window).load(function(){
time = setInterval(function(){
    $('.slideshow-next').trigger('click');
    },5000);

$('#slideshow').hover(function(){
    clearInterval(time);
},function(){
    time = setInterval(function(){
        $('.slideshow-next').trigger('click');
        },5000);
    });
});
```